# How do I make all elements of a webpage appear in the source?

Tags: javascript, python, html, element, inspect

When I press "view-source" (in chrome) of certain webpages, I get some thinned-version of an html, opposed to the more rich version I get when I press "inspect".

I think some content (maybe the scripts) are hidden when you view the source code, and all you get is the script code and not what it translates into.

Is there a way to get the more rich version as an html? (And obviously - if there is - how do you get it?)

Either for download manually, or for when you open a url to read in some program (python urlopen, for example)

Comment: Clearly this can be done, since inspect is doing it. _How are you trying to do it?_ Unless this is a yes-or-no "is this in general possible" question (in which case: "Yes") you need to be more specific about your goals if you want an answer.

Comment: `Ctrl + U` gives u all the html there is. To get other resources like `.js`, `.css` and other media go to the `Network` tab of developer tools.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 The question is how to get the dynamically modified HTML, in full, as I understand it. You've done little more than rephrase what the OP already knows.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read the documentation of the Developer Tools included in the browser you're using.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I think that you can't get the dynamically modified HTML, in full ! Because they are dynamic and may change any moment. But you can get the current HTML in full. Am I wrong? How could someone get the HTML that may or may not come in future?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 I think you could get a snapshot of it in that moment, the way you would press "View Source" if that were your intention, but reflecting what was actually on the page, as does "Inspect", except for the whole page and not just nearby context of the inspected element. I just don't know if OP wants to do this in a browser or with a program or what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What "Show Source" does is give you the actual raw original source file that the browser received from the server. What you see in your browser and what the *Element Inspector* shows you is the current state of the DOM, these days often heavily modified at runtime by Javascript.

source = what the page started with
current DOM = what the page looks like now after dynamic modification

Nothing is being "thinned".

I don't know about your browser, but mine allows me to copy the current DOM as HTML, I just need to select the topmost element:

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I guess I need to get more in depth into web-languages and interfaces.

Comment: Is there a way to get this from Python for example, or from other languages?

Comment: You would need to be *running* the Javascript and a live DOM, like a real browser. For that you would need to control a *headless browser* from Python. Yes, it's possible, but I'd start to question what you're *really* trying to do at that point.

Comment: I'm trying to scrape a website to get some data for a project, instead of doing it manually, which would take me forever. I managed to deal pretty well with the stuff that appear regularly in the html source, but there are some stuff I only get through the javascript...

Comment: That Javascript will be making HTTP requests to the backend to get some data. Look at your browser's network inspector and analyse those HTTP requests, then replicate those and get the raw data.