# How to show completed html source on chrome?

Tags: html

I'm trying to take the full html source of the tab in
[this page](https://www.hotbit.io/rate)

I want to take the source of
[this tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNvpu.jpg)

But unfortunately, the html I'm getting is not completed.
I registered a [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLELG.gif) to explain it better

That select list is showing just when I inspect the element, while If I just insect the element with the list closed, it doesn't return any list html.. is it created dinamically when the user click on it?
I've tried to expand all the codes, but unfortunately it seems the html of every list is not appearing.. It might be created just when I open the list?
Is there a way to get the lists html?
Hope I've been clear.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to save, but by inspecting it sources, it seems that the website use the way of removing and appending the html source which means only you pressed the expanded button, Javascript will append it (different options) to the body, otherwise it will not shown in the element tab.

I don't think you could get all html tags in just 1 try because  the website use Javascript to append the html and you can't see it in the `element section` in `console` when the element is being removed.

Example:

[image]

Comment: exactly what I thought, the website create them just once the user click on the drop list. Btw, I just solved manually because the website is not well coded and I've managed to open every single droplist by hand and they all stay opened. Once I've did that, I took the html.
Anyway, I hope for the future, that I will find a better solution.

Comment: @878757, I don't think you could really find a better solution , The developer tool `Show Source" does is give you the actual raw original source file that the browser received from the server.` It will not able give you what html going to display and rather than checking the developer tool, I don't think you could know which html is going to display (even though you are the developer of the webiste). I just do some research, but seems you can't.You may check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335106/how-do-i-make-all-elements-of-a-webpage-appear-in-the-source Hope this helps

Comment: I've just received an hint about puppeteer, created from Google itself to test websites ui automatically. It can check/simulate javascript code from 
a user input and also you can run Javascript code in the browser which you can use to get access to the html. Btw, Thanks James!

Comment: @878757, you may considered accepting one of the answer if it helps you, this may help further people who look like it

Answer (score 0):

You can save the page if you want. Just save it with Ctrl+S and you will find the basic source in there along with the stylesheet and other scripts.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not asking how to get the html source. 
I'm asking how to take the html that dinamically is being created when the user is clicking on the elements, but in this case the elements are a lot.

Comment: You will get that dynamically when you save it that way. At least give it a try. Then take a look into the source.

Comment: nope, that didn't work. As @james said the website use Javascript to append the html and you can't see it in the element section in console when the element is being removed.. I've tried, did you?

Comment: Once you have the source you can do many things. Do you want the rendered one?